# Modifying the Visual Basic code to run on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, vb6

Please help so that this code works
The verbose text1 entry in Visual Basic into the JavaScript code, please modify

```js
  Web.Document.parentWindow.execScript ("var rowCount = m.rows.length; var row = m.insertRow(rowCount); row.insertCell(0).innerHTML =  Text1.Text  ; ")
```

Comment: Looks pretty valid JS syntax to me already, given `Web.Document.parentWindow.execScript` is defined and is a function

Comment: Jeremy Thille  The code does not work

Comment: What a coincidence. My car doesn't work either. Could you please tell me the exact fix?

Comment: @user6871473 you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask